# Displaying images in one line inside a shorter div

Tags: html, css

How can I set all images in one line and display only the first 200px of them inside the div?
Without breaking the layout, or moving images to a next line.
[online demo](http://www.webdevout.net/test?0U&raw)

```
<div id="thumbsContainer">
   <ul>
    <li><img src="http://img214.imageshack.us/img214/6030/small3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://img263.imageshack.us/img263/5600/small1ga.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://img638.imageshack.us/img638/3521/small4j.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/507/small5.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="
http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/6118/small2o.jpg" alt="" /></li>   
   </ul>
  </div>

#thumbsContainer
{
 width:200px;
 overflow:hidden;

}
ul
{
list-style:none;
}
li
{
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your div width is to short - if you know you image sizes and quantities up front, just fix the div width to fit.

If you want a 200px div with horizontal scrolling, then add 'display:inline' to your list items, and 'overflow:auto' and 'white-space:nowrap' to the div.

If you don't know sizes and/or quantities up front, but you want the list to expand on a single line no matter what, then you may need to use a table.

Comment: I made the div short in order to scroll thr images inside it. So it must be short.

Comment: Then my second suggestion should work for you. You could apply these styles to the div or to the ul, depending on how you want things to look in the final design.

Comment: If I set 'overflow:auto' it works but I get the horizontal scroll bar - i don't want it because i will scroll with javascript

Comment: oh - I see - I think then you will need 'overflow:hidden' - that is the only way I know of to hide the scroll bar. And the table idea wouldn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I set all images in one line

Apply `display:inline` to your `li`s.

> and display only the first 200px of them inside the div?

Apply `width:200px` and `overflow:hidden` to your `div`.